# How to disable TouchableOpacity when pressed? React-Native

Tags: react-native, disable, touchableopacity, onpress

How can I disable TouchableOpacity when I click on it?

This is my code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._pickupHandler(item.p, deliv.party, index)}>
                                            <View style={styles.carg}>
                                                <Text style={styles.delivered_text}>Ok{deliv.loca} {deliv.addres} {deliv.pos} </Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: what do you mean by disable it? like do you want to hide it?

Comment: @GauravRoy No i just want to make it un-clickable!

Answer (score 1):

just pass disabled prop to TouchableOpacity for your example

```
export default class Touchable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      disabled: false,
    };
  }

  onPressButton = (state) => {
    this.setState({
      disabled: state,
    });
  };
  render() {

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.disabled} onPress={() => {
        this.onPressButton(true);
        this._pickupHandler(item.p, deliv.party, index)
      }}>
        <View style={styles.carg}>
          <Text style={styles.delivered_text}>Ok{deliv.loca} {deliv.addres} {deliv.pos} </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How am I suppose to click on it if disable is set to true?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you need another state which will refer to if you want to disable it.

lets make a state var  `TODISABLED` and set it to false initially .

Now suppose you want to disable it after 1 click , you can do this by setting state to true after click  :

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.TODISABLED} onPress={() => {this._pickupHandler(item.p, deliv.party, index);this.setState({TODISABLED:true})}}>
                                            <View style={styles.carg}>
                                                <Text style={styles.delivered_text}>Ok{deliv.loca} {deliv.addres} {deliv.pos} </Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I am doing something similar, I need to set state back to false again so i am doing it in the end of the funciton.